# Concise syntax for "do this or throw an error"

Tags: javascript

A common idiom is javascript and other c-like languages is to use the logical "or" operator like this:

```
function f(x) {
    return (foo(x) || -1);
}
```

which returns -1 if foo(x) returns null (or zero, or the empty string).

What if, instead of returning a different value, I want to throw an error? `throw` is a keyword, not a function, so it can't be used on the right side of `||`. Basically I want to do this:

```
function foo(x) {
    result = bar(x);
    if(result) {return result;}
    throw "bar(x) didn't return a value";
}
```

Can that be made more concise (and less redundant)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you could do

```
function f(x) {
  return foo(x) || (() => { throw "foo(x) didn't return a value"; })();
}
```

or something similar, but there's nothing really wrong with your original code.

You might also try

```
function error(x) { throw x; }
function f(x) { return foo(x) || error("foo(x) didn't return a value"); }
```

although that will report the error occurring inside`error()`.

If it's an option, you could consider re-engineering `bar` or `foo` to throw the error itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use a higher order function:

```
function throw_on_bad(f) {
    var result = f();

    if (result) {
        return result;

    } else {
        throw "Passed function didn't return a value";
    }
}

throw_on_bad(function()  {
    return bar(x));
});
```

Or with ES6:

```
throw_on_bad(() => bar(x));
```

The function that may return a bad result is wrapped in another function to delay execution. If `bar` doesn't take any arguments, it can be written simply as:

```
throw_on_bad(bar);
```

Without macros, it doesn't get much simpler than that